# Coffee mixes eggs

Tags: coffee-culture, cappuccino, egg-coffee

IF you have heard the expression Many Roads to Rome, the same expression applies to enjoying coffee. Yes, there are many ways to enjoy a cup of fragrant and delicious coffee.

Especially for the people of Aceh, drinking coffee has become part of an inseparable lifestyle. You want to taste Acehnese filtered coffee or sanger (coffee mixed milk), or espresso, everything is there. In fact, because of the large number of coffee shops in Banda Aceh, the capital of Aceh Province was dubbed the Thousand State Coffee Shop.

In addition to those already mentioned above, there are other ways to enjoy coffee by mixing it with eggs. Eggs that are used are not eggs, but chicken eggs are believed to be beneficial for health. In addition to coffee shops, this concoction is usually sold in places where traditional herbal medicine is sold on the roadside. This whipped egg mixed with coffee is said to increase vitality. Hm ... really?

Is drinking coffee mixed with eggs harmful to health?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGgZJ.jpg]

Aceh, an area also known as one of Nusantara's best coffee barns, has an enticing coffee variant. Even coffee shops in Aceh are never empty of visitors, presenting various forms of coffee creation for the audience. For the people of Aceh, drinking coffee is not only daily traditions. Drinking coffee can also increase stamina, or the people of Aceh often call it poding. The true coding is coffee mixed with eggs. Coffee and eggs are dishes that come from a mixture of coffee after filtering the pulp and mixing the eggs.
Although it has been mixed with eggs, the aroma of the coffee still feels, and does not smell fishy. To get rid of fishy odors, the eggs that have been shaken use a mixer and then soaked in hot water. Then given a mixture of coffee and a little sweetened condensed milk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can assume it's as safe as drinking eggnog. (eggnog a drink made from raw eggs, milk, spices and sometimes alcohol)

I think the "level of safety" depends on which country you take the egg from. In some countries, eating an egg raw is safe, but in other countries it's not (like in Canada and United-States)

Basically, I GUESS you wouldn't get sick if you drink it once, but if you get the habit of drinking it often, the chance of getting sick gets higher.

If you drink it, please tell us if it's good! :)

Comment: Raw eggs are safe to eat and even healthy in general if they haven't been contaminated with salmonella (in the US e.g. it should be considered safe since only 1 in 30000 eggs or so is contaminated). The chances of that increase of course when the hygienic circumstances in production aren't optimal. In this case though we are not talking about raw eggs since we are mixing them with hot coffee, which kills salmonella as long as the coffee is hot when the egg is mixed in. To be absolutely safe they'd need to be exposed to heat above 70°C for 10min.

Comment: I personally am a coffee connoisseur and I have also tried several types of coffee and different ways of serving. Yes, I like coffee mixed with chicken eggs, even I drink coffee mixed with this egg twice a month, but with bitter coffee, it doesn't mix with sugar or milk. I have not felt any symptoms for health. therefore I want to discuss here about the effects of coffee eggs according to medical experts.

Comment: Thank you, friend, for this kind of response I have been waiting for in this discussion. this explanation is very logical

Comment: in eggnog, it's the alcohol that's making it safe by killing any bacteria. if you instead heat it up to 70C for 10 min, you have scrambled egg with coffee. not what you'd want, i think.